# Marketing Cloud - Fast and simple way to get list subscriber counts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, c#

Is there any way to retrieve list subscriber counts without actually retrieving the list subscribers themselves?  Retrieving the subscribers can be slow, especially with large lists, and for my purposes, I only need the count, not the actual objects.

I'm using the Marketing Cloud/Exact Target c# SOAP API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately SFMC SOAP API doesn't provide any count function. you have to retrieve all records and build your own calculation.

Comment: Bummer.  That's what I'm currently doing, but hoping there was a better, faster way.  Thanks for responding though!